# lockAndInitHandle error on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, lwjgl

I am developing a Java App using Lwjgl-2.9.1 on a Windows 8 PC.
I am using Eclipse (Kepler) as developing Tool.
Running the App in Eclipse works fine. But when I pack the App
in a jar file, and run it from a .bat file,
using Jdk 1.7-45, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndInitHandle(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/awt/Canvas;Z)Z
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndInitHandle(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.access$100(AWTSurfaceLock.java:51)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock$1.run(AWTSurfaceLock.java:94)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock$1.run(AWTSurfaceLock.java:92)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.privilegedLockAndInitHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:92)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndGetHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsAWTGLCanvasPeerInfo.doLockAndInitHandle(WindowsAWTGLCanvasPeerInfo.java:58)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.PeerInfo.lockAndGetHandle(PeerInfo.java:85)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTGLCanvas.paint(AWTGLCanvas.java:320)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:264)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:240)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:347)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4937)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

After confirming the source for the `AWTSurfaceLock` class, it looks like the error is generated
when calling a native function in a Dll file.
The native function called is: `lockAndInitHandle(lock_buffer, component);` (2 arguments)
But according to different sites on the internet some versons of the class `AWTSurfaceLock` calls the function with a third argument:
`lockAndInitHandle(ByteBuffer lock_buffer, Canvas component, Canvas display_parent)`

What version of `Lwjgl` and and Java JDK should I use?
Does Eclipse run its own JRE?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation of Lwjgl](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application): `java -Djava.library.path="natives/" -jar MyJar.jar`

or alternatively: `System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("natives").getAbsolutePath());`

Because the native libraries need to be found.

In Eclipse, I suppose you have set the native path in your project.